# PromiseKit: can't call custom code between then handlers

Tags: swift, promisekit

Just started with PromiseKit and running into a weird
compile problem:

- with firstly: Ambiguous reference to member 'firstly(execute:)' ()
- without firstly: Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Promise

```
func test(someValue: Int) -> Promise<Void> {
    return Promise { seal in
        // do something with someValue
        seal.fulfill(())
    }
}
```

This works:

```
firstly {
    test(someValue: 2)
}.then {
    test(someValue: 1)
}.catch { error in
    ...
}
```

but this one doesn't:

```
firstly {
    test(someValue: 2)
}.then {
    let dd = 1
    return test(someValue: dd)
}.catch { error in
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Promises quite a bit lately and I've run into similar errors, seems like sometimes all the closures and generics get the best of the compiler.

What I've found is that you should *always* have a `done` call if you have a `catch` call, add it right before the `catch`. `done` means you won't be chaining your promise any more and you can then use a `PKFinalizer`, like the `catch` call is.

And if your promises have parameters you're not using, make sure to add `_ in` on your next `then`/`done` call, or you can add a `asVoid()` call in between, which discards the result.

EDIT:

This week I also had an error where adding an extra line to the closure made it fail. Since what I was doing was converting one promise into multiple promises, I used `flatMapThen`. There are several methods on `Promise` that you can use for different results. You can use `get` if you want to store the result from a promise and continue, or map if you want to convert the result into another type.

For example, I would translate your failing error into this

```
firstly {
    test(someValue: 2)
}.map {
    1
}.then {
    test(someValue: $0)
}.done {
    print("success")
}.catch { error in
    ...
}
```

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but the example above still doesn't compile. :(

Comment: @Markus I added some more info to my answer

Comment: Thank you! That's a great work around, I spent the entire afternoon trying to get it to work, should have posted sooner ;)